i Have Error with making the Auth Logic in Laravel
this is my login logic when i try it give me error down blow
 public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'Email'=>'required',
            'password'=> 'required'
        ]);

        $agent =  DB::table('agents')->where('Email',$request->Email)->first();


        if($request->password == $agent->password || Hash::check($request->password,$agent->password))
        {
            Auth::login($agent);
            return redirect()->route('agent.index');
        }
        
        else 
        {
            return dd('no');
        }

The Error :
Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login(): Argument #1 ($user) must be of type Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, App\Models\agent given, called in C:\xampps\htdocs\Laravel\Laravel-10\REV\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager.php on line 340
i new to laravel so i did not try much cause i know very little about authentication and login logic also how to deal with middleware
so please if u dont have answer to my question i need help on from where i could know more about auth and middleware and deg deeper in Laravel beside the documentation

I would suggest using Auth::attempt() to validate your credentials instead of trying to check it yourself. It will also log in if validated.

The error is complaining that the agent must be of a type Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, which means you're not using extends Authenticatable on your model.

aynber i used the attempt method and still not working

Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable
and for this one i dont know how to implement it inside the model

You can't use the agents model or the table to authenticate users straight out of the box.
According to the Laravel documentation:

By default, Laravel includes an App\Models\User Eloquent model in your app/Models directory. This model may be used with the default Eloquent authentication driver.

This means that Laravel uses the User model to authenticate users. So, you could stick with the User model that Laravel comes with or customize the default authentication driver to fit your needs. I'd recommend sticking with the default authentication driver, but it's ultimately up to you.
You can take a look at these references for how to create a custom authentication guard.
Laravel official documentation
How to use auth guard in laravel

oh that what i found out when i check the user model and see that is authenticatable .
but also after i edit the config/auth.php file to agent model it still not changed is there away to change it from user model to agent model or any other mode
// i just new learner thank you for ur replay to my error and if there any source i could know more about authentication beside the docs please let me know

@AhmedMahamedAbdallh, if you're working on building something, always remember to stick to the User model provided by Laravel for authentication if you're thinking about role-based access control. Check out this thread (https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/livewire/how-to-create-custom-guard-login-and-register-in-laravel-livewire) for some good insights on whether to use a custom guard or roles.

I'm not entirely sure why you're searching for the Agent model first, but you should follow these steps:
After retrieving your agent, you need to find the User model because the login method expects an object of the User model.
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'Email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    // Retrieve the agent
    $agent = DB::table('agents')->where('Email', $request->Email)->first();

    // Retrieve the user associated with the agent
    $user = User::where('id', $agent->user_id)->first();

    // Log in the user
    Auth::login($user);
}


oh that what i found out when i check the user model and see that is authenticatable .
but also after i edit the config/auth.php file to agent model it still not changed is there away to change it from user model to agent model or any other mode
// i just new learner thank you for ur replay to my error and if there any source i could know more about authentication beside the docs please let me know
